# Reset stored jQuery option values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I'm using a group of select boxes (compound filter) that disable items when certain options are selected. I'm trying to use it with isotope as a simple way of disabling combinations that are not available. Everything works great except that the script seems to be storing the last combination picked.

I used functions that were recommended by the developer to reset isotope and I also reset the filters. It works, the filters (select boxes) are reset to the default "All", the items within the select boxes are re-enabled, and the isotope grid is reset to show all items. When I go to use the filters again, new items that I select do not show up anymore, as if the previously selected filters are still enabled.

What am I doing wrong? How can I reset everything completely, short of refreshing the page?

*Note that I did not include Isotope in this example below.*

```
$(function() {
  var $selects = $('select[name*="select"]').change(function(e) {
    var val = this.value;
    $selects.not(this).find('option').prop('disabled', function() {
      return this.value === val || $(this).hasClass(val)
    })

  })
  $('.button--reset').on( 'click', function() {
  $('.grid').isotope({
        filter: '*',
  });
  $('.option-set').val('*');
  $selects.val('').find('option').prop('disabled', false)
  });
});

<div class="">
  <select name="select-type" id="select-type">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option class="Small Medium Red Yellow" value="Apple">Apple</option>
        <option class="Small Large Red Green" value="Pear">Pear</option>
        <option class="Medium Large Green Yellow" value="Strawberry">Strawberry</option>     
      </select>
</div>

<div class="">
  <select name="select-size" id="select-size">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option class="Apple Pear Green Yellow" value="Small">Small</option>
        <option class="Apple Strawberry Red Green" value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option class="Pear Strawberry Red Yellow" value="Large">Large</option>  
      </select>
</div>

<div class="">
  <select name="select-color" id="select-color">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option class="Apple Pear Medium Large" value="Red">Red</option>
        <option class="Pear Strawberry Small Medium" value="Green">Green</option>
        <option class="Apple Strawberry Small Large" value="Yellow">Yellow</option>      
      </select>
</div>

<button class="button button--reset">Reset</button>
```

I hope that makes sense. Thanks for any help

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xv8hu4fk/ 
It seems worked correctly on this jsfiddle, isn't it?

Comment: @vicnoob yes, but it doesn't seem to release the stored values when I add it to my isotope script. For example, I select strawberry, small, red and then click reset. The filters reset, the grid resets, but it's as if the items are still selected when I go select new options from the filter. I click pear and it shows nothing because small and red are still engaged in the background.

Comment: can you add your isotope script to that jsfiddle, I can try to debug it

Comment: you are not provided the `.option-set` value. add your all script in jsfiddle and give us the link to find a solution for you